# Barchart 3d in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

How to draw 3d barcharts with [ECGraph](http://code.google.com/p/ecgraph/)? I am able to draw in 2d but I want in 3d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that ECGraph has not implemented 3D barcharts yet. It supports 2D curve chart and histogram at this moment.